# EXE-шник, сделанный в Pyinstaller, не запускается, хотя в vscode все работает

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, pysimplegui

Код (частично):

```
#coding=utf-8
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import zipfile
#import razmetka

def main():
    
    layout = [.........
```

написан на python3.9.0 и запускает интерфейс с кнопками.Используется библиотека PySimpleGUI для этого.
Далее делаю EXE-шник с помощью pyinstaller.  Делал в маке и винде   -  exe-шник не запускается. Ошибок не выдает. Что может быть?

Comment: Что касается других библиотек, то exe работает

Comment: Еще не пробовал никогда через pysimplegui-exemaker"

Comment: проблема связана с тем, что есть импорт библиотек pytesseract и pytesseract-ocr, а их импорт связан с использованием бинарных файлов. вот эти бинарные файлы и не затягиваются в пакет, в том числе и принудительно. Как решать проблему, не понятно.Значит, что exe делается не для всех библиотек python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была в бинарниках библиотеки PySimpleGUI. Они не добавлялись в exe при его формировании. Пришлось их отдельно добавлять вручную.